# How do I troubleshoot an unresponsive WSL2 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Usually, WSL2 runs fine, but maybe once a month or two, it becomes completely unresponsive and I'm not sure why. Usually restarting the entire computer fixes it, but **I'd like to know if there is any way to troubleshoot this** and, ideally, prevent it from happening. I also want to know if this could be caused by system corruption.

There's *a lot* of information in this post, but I attempted arrange it in order of importance. Please be aware the bullet points are numbered in the order in which I *wrote* this post: "Symptoms", "System Information", then "30-60 minutes later".

## Symptoms:

1. When I attempt to run wsl.exe in powershell/cmd.exe, the command hangs:

   [image: cmd.exe]

   I've been waiting for this to do something for over 10+ minutes now.  The same thing occurs via attempt to `wsl.exe --shutdown`:

   [image: powershell]
2. When I start a WSL terminal, it opens a window, but it is similarly unresponsive:

   [image: WSL Terminal]
3. I don't normally open a WSL terminal directly. Usually I open mintty.exe/wsltty via a shortcut that runs this command: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\wsltty\bin\mintty.exe --tabbar=4 -o "KeyFunctions=t:new-window-cwd;w:close" --WSL="Ubuntu" --configdir="%APPDATA%\wsltty" -`. Like the other examples, these all hang:

   [image: Ubuntu Terminal]

## 30-60 minutes later:

1. Roughly 30-60 minutes into writing this post, the bottom Ubuntu window you see in point 3 closed on its own. Now the top Ubuntu window says it's installing, the cmd.exe's `wsl.exe` command errored out, but the powershell window remains unresponsive:

   [image]

   [image]
2. About 10 minutes later, the powershell's `wsl.exe` command errored out too:

   [image]

   I think this delay is due to running the powershell command roughly ten minutes after the cmd.exe command.
3. About five minutes later, the Ubuntu window closed on its own.
4. The vmmem.exe process is *still* not running, which concerns me, but I haven't retried anything yet.
5. The Microsoft store says that I'm using this version of Ubuntu. Unfortunately, as I mentioned in point 10, I don't know if this is any different from before the install occurred.

   [image]
6. Unfortunately, when I try to do anything with WSL, I still have all the same symptoms I described at the beginning.
7. I'm going to restart now but if that fixes it, that'll limit my ability to provide information until it happens again. I've exported a list of running services to a file in case it helps to see what was active during this issue.

## System Information:

1. I installed (and upgraded) WSL2 months ago and use it almost daily.
2. When I go into the task manager, I notice the vmmem.exe process is not running. That feels important, but I don't know how to *start* it; I can only find people asking how to stop or restart it, and those answers all use `wsl.exe`. As you can see in the Symptoms section, I can't use that command right now.
3. According to the task manager, my CPU usage is around 0-5%. When I sort by usage, descending, I don't see anything WSL2 related in the top ten.
4. According to the task manager, my Memory usage is around 50%. When I sort by usage, descending, I don't see anything WSL2 related in the top ten.
5. Windows update says I'm up to date (I checked while writing this):

   [image]
6. There was one optional update available, but for some reason, whenever I install this, my system can no longer connect to the Internet.

   [image]
7. I've installed Ubuntu from the Windows Store, and I'm interpreting from the UI, that it doesn't need an update:

   [image]

   I wish I could find exactly what version is installed, but I'm not sure how to find that in this UI.

   **Update:** Now I see you need to scroll past most of the content to find this information. Unfortunately I only noticed this after step 12, so I'm not sure what version I had at the time of writing this bullet point.
8. Although Ubuntu is installed from the Windows Store, WSL2 is not. Apparently I downloaded and installed it manually. According to my "Apps & features" settings, I'm running this version:

   [image]

   If `wsl.exe` says a different version, I'll come back and edit this line. At the moment, I'm unable to provide that information because the only way I know how is to run `wsl.exe`, and `wsl.exe` currently hangs.

Comment: Uninstall everything then reinstall WSL from the Microsoft Store and after that is installed should you install WSL distribution

Comment: I'm sure this is TMI as it is, but I was able to resolve this. The details of my journey are documented here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11067#issuecomment-1911527056 TL;DR: [reinstall WSL](https://gist.github.com/4wk-/889b26043f519259ab60386ca13ba91b), toggle the win10 feature named Hyper-V, and avoid running `wsl --upgrade`. I've yet to confirm which of those last two are necessary, but I'm pretty confident at least 1 is.

Comment: Hyper-V isn’t required for WSL.

Comment: @Ramhound Hm. [Is the faq out of date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#does-wsl-2-use-hyper-v--will-it-be-available-on-windows-10-home-and-windows-11-home-)? Maybe what it means is "Virtual Machine Platform" sets up its own Hyper-V so I don't need to check the box?

Comment: If you read the prerequisites for WSL2, the documentation clearly indicates. that Virtual Machine Platform is required not Hyper-V. So the FAQ you linked to is not out of date.  **"The newest version of WSL uses Hyper-V architecture to enable its virtualization. This architecture will be available in the 'Virtual Machine Platform' optional component. This optional component will be available on all SKUs.""**

Comment: @Ramhound I may have misunderstood the point of your ["Hyper-V isn’t required for WSL"](https://superuser.com/questions/1825580/how-do-i-troubleshoot-an-unresponsive-wsl2-on-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment2881471_1825580) comment. Is it to rule out Hyper-V as the cause of my WSL problems?

Comment: "toggle the win10 feature named Hyper-V" - This could be taken two days.  If it's enabled you disable Hyper-V, likewise, it could also mean if it's disabled you enable it.  My comment was to indicate that Hyper-V is not required for WSL to be functional.

Comment: @Ramhound ah. Now I understand. I'll clarify: Hyper-V was checked for me. I unchecked, restarted, checked, restarted. From your comment I see it wasn't necessary for it to be on in the first place. I'm not sure how it got like that.